# How to hide color axis in heatmaps using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I don't want to show color axis in heatmap which is always visible at the bottom of heatmap. I tried to set enable to false but it is not affecting the result. How to hide color axis in heatmap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the enabled flag on the legend, not the colorAxis itself. The colorAxis is what powers the colours of the chart, but the legend is what actually displays the slider.

```
legend: {
 enabled: false
}
```

Comment: Setting this to false, changes my heatmap's colors. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I guess it depends on your other settings, do you have an example?

Comment: @Bajena I have also witnessed the color changes you mentioned. I could fix it by setting all standard color gradient values manually, i.e. `min`, `max`, `minColor`, `maxColor` and the `stops`. But the stops are no longer relative to your set `min` and `max` but the actual underlying values.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as @Bajena. I've created a new question that can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557590/highcharts-heatmap-disabling-the-legend-results-in-different-colors. How can I get the colors to stay the same, but still disable the legend?