# Highcharts heatmap - disabling the legend results in different colors

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I am using a Highcharts heatmap and if I disable the legend by setting

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

the colors used in the chart are different. I am also providing some colorAxis info like a min, max and stops. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbgarr/8c2L6sdf/) that illustrates the issue I'm having.

How can I get Highcharts to use the same colors that it uses when the legend is enabled, but disable the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a possibly bug, so I reported that to our developers here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5205

Workaround:

- set `tickPositions` for colorAxis - http://jsfiddle.net/vLtc1tz6/1/
- set to false `startOnTick` and endOnTick for colorAxis - http://jsfiddle.net/vLtc1tz6/2/

Comment: Thank you for passing that on to your team. It seems they have already posted a work around that works for me (actually both methods they mentioned seemed to work). Go ahead and post them here and I'll mark your answer as correct.